# Budget not exhausted but not getting spent google ads

Tags: google-ads

I am very confused, I have a daily budget of $5/day for my ad campaign. But today it spent $0.27 for 5 clicks. It only got 143 impressions. Now here is where stuff gets very confusing, my budget is obviously not exhausted, so maybe it's the keywords. Nope, my keywords are :

- browser games: Low competition, 10k to 100k monthly searches
- messaging : low competition, 100k to 1 million monthly searches
- online games : medium competition, 100k to 1 million monthly searches

How is it possible that I am getting so few impressions, when my budget isn't even exhausted. Would increasing the daily budget help?

Comment: Is your bid (cost per click) sufficient? Are you using a smart bidding algorithm?

Comment: How do I change that in google ads? My campaign is smart mode

Comment: In case you use target CPA bidding, you can try raising the target cost per conversion and check if impressions improve. Or if you use a bidding like Enhanced CPC, you can directly raise the CPC bid and check.

Comment: Is your campaign new?

Comment: Yeah it's pretty new. I use CPC. How do I raise the CPC bid?

Comment: Pls refer https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2470113?hl=en . I am compiling my points below as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low impressions in google ads are generally the result of one of the below three main reasons

1. Low budget, 2. Low bids or 3) Low ad quality

Ref: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7103386?hl=en

If the daily budget hasn't been spent, then the reason could be either low bid or ad quality issues.

Raising bids for CPC campaigns is discussed in detail at https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2470113?hl=en

Regarding ad quality, Google looks at various factors like keyword relevancy, expected CTR etc. You may have to re-check your ad copy and optimize if needed. It is good to check the ad copy for keyword relevance, value propositions, clarity of the message, offer, incentive, etc.